# Desktop Firebase

Tags: java, firebase

Доброго времени суток. Возникла потребность написать десктопное приложение для windows, реализующая очень простую схему взаимодействие с БД firebase. Все что нужно делать- заносить новые посты в БД. Попробовал найти материал в интернете, но немного смущает то, что даже нельзя добавить новое приложение на Java в окне добавления новых приложений.

Казалось бы, есть [квикстарт](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java), но надпись "demonstrating the Firebase APIs using the Java Server SDK" меня немного смущает, да и дата последнего обновления- 8 месяцев назад (до покупки гуглом, если не изменяет память). Java Server SDK это вообще что? Как подключить к обычному Java проекту и будут ли работать импорты Gradle, предназначеные для андроид?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We currently don't have an SDK that is intended for Java desktop apps. We do have a Java server SDK, but it requires a service account which is not secure to include in a desktop app. Your options are to either use the Realtime Database's REST API or communicating with Firebase via your own custom server using the Java server SDK.

[Цинк](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/NLm5PfHWNZg) - пост годичной давности, но не думаю, что сильно устарел.

Посмотрите на рекомендованный [Rest API FirebaseJ](https://github.com/bane73/firebase4j) - правда все еще в глубокой альфе.

Так что прогноз неутешительный.

Возьмите другую облачную БД, благо их сейчас уже много развелось.

Comment: Хорошо, а есть SDK на С++ именно для ПК? Насколько я понял, есть поддержка С++, но только в плане написания на android